# Как написать класс который выполняет функцию это кода(функция кода в сортировке букв в алфавитном порядке)?

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char **mass = new char *[8];


    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        mass[i] = new char[20];
        cin >> mass[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++)
            if (mass[i] > mass[j]) {
                char* tmp = mass[i];
                mass[i] = mass[j];
                mass[j] = tmp;
            }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        cout << mass[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если очень-очень грубо переписать, то где то так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Task
{
    public:
        void input() {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                std::string s;
                std::cin >> s;
                mass.push_back(s);
            }
        }
        void sort() {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
                    if (mass[i] > mass[j]) {
                        std::string tmp = mass[i];
                        mass[i] = mass[j];
                        mass[j] = tmp;
                    }
            }
        }
        void print() {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                cout << mass[i] << " ";
            }
        }
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> mass;
        const int size = 8;
};


int main() {
    Task t;
    t.input();
    t.sort();
    t.print();   

    return 0;
}
```

И да, сортировку лучше на std::sort заменить.

```
#include <algorithm>
// ...

    void sort() {
        std::sort(mass.begin(), mass.end());
    }
```

Заодно и утечку памяти случайно пофиксили. Этот код не идеален, но он более плюсовый. Ну так, на четверть плюсика.

Comment: а можно не через векторы?

Comment: Можно, но не нужно. Вы же на с++ пишете, а не на с. vector - это то, что нужно использовать, если нужен "массив". Но если очень-очень хочется - аккуратно перенесите свой код.